Convergence of series regarding symmetric difference
I am trying to understand the following exercise ($\Delta$ means the symmetric difference i.e. $A \Delta B$ contains all elements which are either in $A$ or in $B$):

Let $X$ be a non-empty-set and $A_n \subset X, \ \forall n \in \mathbb N$ and $\mathcal B(X)$ be the powerset of $X$. Then the series $\sum_{n\geq 1} A_n$ formed in the abelian group $(\mathcal B (X), \Delta)$ converges iff $\lim_{n\to\infty} A_n = \emptyset$.

Now, I got confused in what way I should understand the convergence of the series $\sum_{n\geq 1} A_n$? Is it in the sense that
$$\limsup_k \sum_{1\leq n\leq k} A_n = \liminf_k \sum_{1\leq n\leq k} A_n,$$
where I can use the standard definition of
$$\limsup_k \sum_{1\leq n\leq k} A_n = \bigcap_{k \geq 1}\bigcup_{m\geq k} \sum_{1\leq n\leq m} A_n$$
or respectively with the definition of the $\liminf$?.
And: $\sum_{1\leq n\leq m} A_n = A_1 \Delta \ldots \Delta A_m$?
I do not look for an answer just for clarification.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Where is this exercise from?

It is from the german book "Maß- und Integrationstheorie" by Jürgen Elstrodt. I do not think that there exists an english translation.

Is the summation with respect to symmetric difference?

@Keen-ameteur Yes, I wrote that at the end maybe it was not clear enough!

Some thing is unclear to me. If you take $A_n= A\neq \emptyset$ constant, then $\sum A_n$ should converge to $\emptyset$ but $\lim A_n= A$.

Hmm.. why would that converge? Wouldn't it jump between $\emptyset$ and $A$? Because $A \Delta A = \emptyset$ but $\emptyset \Delta A = A$. So like the series $\sum_{n\geq 1} (-1)^n$

Yes, rather likely the limit here is in the sense of the set-theoretic limit. And yes, the partial sums in the series are undoubtedly with respect to the symmetric difference $\triangle$, since that was taken as the abelian group operation.
Then the theorem holds. For each partial sum contains an $x \in X$ iff $x$ has thus far appeared in an odd number of the sets $A_n$. This kind of behaviour therefore stabilises iff no $x \in X$ is infinitely often in $(A_n)$ which is precisely $\limsup{A_n} = \varnothing$.
Further suggestions:

always emphasize when you mean non-inclusive disjunction when using "or", even if it is obvious what is meant (as in your description of the symmetric difference operation);
I would never (globally) use any notation for the power set of $X$ besides $\mathcal P(X)$, $2^{X}$ or their equivalent variants;
it is useful to prove first some alternative descriptions of the $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ and to instead use these descriptions instead of the often more tedious union-intersections;
from the comments: yes, if $(A_n)$ is a constant sequence, then (as is also implied by the theorem) the series converges iff that constant is the empty set. You correctly point out that otherwise we will have oscillation between the non-empty constant and empty set. Note that a useful way of thinking about this is that any set which is closed wrt the symmetric difference is not only an abelian group, but also a vector space over $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

